# Return random results ( order by rand() )

Tags: mysql, random

I remember reading somewhere that using order by rand() is bad and I just startpaged it and found an article that proves it. Order by rand() can be extremely slow with large databases and the suggested solution was to generate a random number in php and select based upon it. The problem is that I need to verify other fields in order to return my records. I may also have some old records deleted, that may also cause an issue. Can anyone provide a decent way to select a few random records from a table that match certain conditions ( for example field `paid` must be equal to 1 ) ?

Comment: if you use php, use the 'shuffle' function.
so get your results and then shuffle them in your program.

Comment: But what if I have 100,000 results returned, I don't want to fetch all of that

Comment: @FabianBigler pulling a large number of results into php to get just a few is likely to be much slower than `order by rand() limit N`.

Comment: And @php_nub_qq is the table MyISAM or INNODB

Comment: @Kevin it is currently MyISAM but I may consider converting if I have no other options

Comment: so select the min pk that is greater then some random number (and whatever other criteria you need)

Comment: @php_nub_qq Good point. Was just an idea, turned out to be bad for many results, though.

Answer (score 8):

The reason that ordering by `RAND()` can be slow is that you're forcing the database to actually sort the whole table before returning anything. Just reducing the load to a single table scan is much faster (albeit still somewhat slow).

This means that you could get part of the way just by avoiding the ordering:

```
  SELECT *
    FROM my_table
   WHERE RAND() < 0.1
ORDER BY RAND()
   LIMIT 100
```

This will select approximately 1% of all the rows in the table, sort them and return the top 100. Just note that the main issue here (as well as with @cmd's answer) is that you can't be sure that the query returns anything at all.

The approach above should involve a whole table scan (to decide which rows to use) followed by a sort of approximately 1% of the rows. If you have a lot of rows, you can reduce the percentage accordingly.

Comment: I need to be sure that I will return something and I need to be sure that the returned records are completely random. If there's no better option I would use @cmd's suggestion and run a few queries more.

Comment: But @cmd's suggestion has the same weakness - you can't be sure it'll return anything.

Comment: Why not? I don't see how it might not return anything.

Comment: ...and the answer above uses ``RAND()`` which is much more random than just selecting using the primary key (which obviously skews heavily towards high numbers).

Comment: If the random number is higher than all pk_id. But anyway, it is very, very skewed towards the high numbers, so you won't be getting anything near an even distribution.

Comment: I was thinking more about something like
`SELECT id FROM table WHERE id>(floor(rand() * (max(id)-min(id)))+min(id)) LIMIT 1;`
But I'm getting
`#1111 - Invalid use of group function` O.o

Comment: If you need just 8 records, you can tune the parameter to return something in the order of 1000 rows before the ``LIMIT``. It will then be extremely unlikely that the query doesn't return anything (so unlikely that the server running this code is more likely to get struck by lighting and run over by a bulldozer at the same time). Sorting 1000 records is so cheap that it shouldn't measure at all.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/31213/discussion-between-php-nub-qq-and-mzedeler)

Comment: You can doo that too, but you need to make sure that your ids aren't skewed. Gaps will lead to skewed results. Otherwise, just ad a new column with a sequence without gaps and do it like this: ``SELECT * FROM my_table WHERE id > (SELECT FLOOR(RAND() * MAX(id) - MIN(id)) FROM table) LIMIT 1``.

Comment: The problem with this approach (like @cmd indicates) is that you can only select one row at a time. Running this eight times isn't a very good idea. Then I'd get ``MIN(id)`` and ``MAX(id)`` out of the database, generate eight random numbers, and run a query to select all of them at once. Otherwise you'll wind up scanning the whole table eight times in a row (unless the database does some clever caching).

Answer (score 2):

How random do you need them to be? if you dont need a super even distribution try this

```
select min(pk_id) from my_table where pk_id > %(random_number)s and paid=1
```

where `%(random_number)s` is a bind variable containing a random number from `0` to `max(pk_id)-1` regenerated each time you run the query

Comment: That is a nice idea, but I cannot afford to risk displaying the same set of results numerous times. That will just tell people I have a bad randomizing system. +rep though

Comment: @php_nub_qq it will be a different record each time if you generate a new random number each time you perform the query

Comment: Yes I know but I need to return 2 to 8 records, which I refer to as a set, and if the random number shall be max(pk_id)-8 ( which I'd set as max rand number ) then pk_id-7 and pk_id-6 will always be shown. And if 8 is the number of records I need to return last 8 will always be consecutive. I don't want to run 8 separate queries

Comment: @php_nub_qq this is to get a single record randomly, it the table is large (only time order by rand is a problem) then you can just call it several times to get your set

Comment: I don't think the query as written will work at all. SELECT MAX(ID) WHERE ID > <some value> will always reuturn the same MaxID? (the biggest one that exists in the table)  I think you want to do a SELECT TOP (x) order by the PK where ID > <some random number) instead -- or a SELECT MIN(ID) WHERE ID > @some Random Number -- Note not downvoting but I think you've made a logical mistake

Comment: @TransactCharlie yeah, you are right, I ment `min`.  corrected, thanks

Comment: @cmd It won't necessarily be a different record, even if you generate a new random number every time.  If you have gaps in the key or if the distribution is skewed after the condition is taken into account (paid=1), then it will be possible to generate a set of random numbers that would return identical results.