# How to shuffle a table of records in Delphi?

Tags: mysql, delphi, random, shuffle, records

I have a table of questions each with a category and I want to query the database to first find questions of a specific category, and then retrieve a random question from that category. I was planning on doing this by shuffling all the records so they are in no particular order in the table, and then finding the first question that has the category I'm looking for. 
I know this will work, I just have no idea how to shuffle all the records in the table to get them in a random order. Anybody got any ideas on how to do this? Or an alternate method I could use? Thanks in advance.
- George

Comment: You can't *shuffle the records in a table* if by *table* you mean *database table* and by *records* you mean *rows*. Databases don't understand "shuffling". Many SQL dialects offer an RANDOM() function you can use to generate pseudo-values for an artificial column, and you can ORDER BY that column, or you can retrieve the ID values from each row into an array in Delphi, shuffle that array, retrieve a value from a random array element, and use that to query and retrieve the matching row from the DB. If you can provide the table def and confirm what you're asking, we can probably help.

Comment: Fetching random results from a MySQL table: http://stackoverflow.com/q/16928079/33732

Comment: Don't shule your questions in database. And I realy mean don't. Doing so all you will create is lots of work for your database. Instead filter all your question based on certain category. Then generate random number from 0 to number of filtered database records. And then retrieve N'th qustion from that filtered list of your qustions. Now I don't know how to achive that with database becouse my knowledge on working with them is to small but I still understand the logic of how to do this.

Answer (score 0):

Generally, it depends of your database. Just for example, in Oracle you can shuffle records using

```
select <fields>
from questions
where <some-conditions>
order by dbms_random.value
```

But I doubt if it good approach generally. You should either query 'give me one random question of every category' if you wish so, or, closer to real tasks, just fetch all questions and make some filtering on the client.

Comment: Judging my the question's tags, the database is known to be MySQL.

Comment: Why do you doubt that it's a good approach? You can't just write that without explanation.

Comment: I mentioned RANDOM in my comment above, and if your only content is the same information for the totally wrong database (the question is clearly tagged MySQL), I don't see how this adds any value here.